# Creating a udf in bigquery to match array inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a udf to match array's in biqquery, essentially if there are values of x array in y array then I want the result to be true.

e.g. match_rows([4,5,6], [5,6,7] should return true.

I've written this out but I keep getting syntax error's and i'm not familiar enough with what i'm doing to be able to debug so was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on what is going on.

Specific error = `No matching signature for function match_rows for argument types: ARRAY, ARRAY. Supported signature: match_rows(ARRAY, ARRAY) at [44:1]`

````
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION match_rows(arr1 ARRAY<FLOAT64>, arr2 ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
  RETURNS BOOL
  LANGUAGE js AS 
  """
function findCommonElements2(arr1, arr2) { 

    // Create an empty object 
    let obj = {}; 

        // Loop through the first array 
        for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 

            // Check if element from first array 
            // already exist in object or not 
            if(!obj[arr1[i]]) { 

                // If it doesn't exist assign the 
                // properties equals to the  
                // elements in the array 
                const element = arr1[i]; 
                obj[element] = true; 
            } 
        } 

        // Loop through the second array 
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length ; j++) { 

        // Check elements from second array exist 
        // in the created object or not 
        if(obj[arr2[j]]) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
} 
""";

WITH input AS (
  SELECT STRUCT([5,6,7] as row, 'column2' as value) AS test
)
  SELECT
match_rows([4,4,6],[4,7,8]),
match_rows(test.row, test.row)

  FROM input ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ARRAY<FLOAT64>` you are passing `ARRAY<INT64>` to your function. Therefore, the `No matching signature` error. In order to solve this error, you can just assign one of the values in your array as float, the syntax is below:

```
WITH input AS (
#notice that the first element is a float and so the whole array is ARRAY<FLOAT64>
  SELECT STRUCT([5.0,6,7] as row, 'column2' as value) AS test
)
  SELECT
#the same as it was done above, first element explicitly as float
match_rows([4.0,4,6],[4,7,8]),
match_rows(test.row, test.row)

  FROM input
```

However, I have tested your function and I have realised that the syntax of your *JavaScript UDF* is not according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure). The syntax should be as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION multiplyInputs(x FLOAT64, y FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
    //write directly your transformations here
    return x*y;
""";
```

Notice that, it is not needed to especify `function findCommonElements2(arr1, arr2)`, you can go directly to the body of your function because the function's name is defined after the statement `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION`.

In addition, I have also figured out that your function was not returning the desired output. For this reason, I have written a simpler JavaScript UDF which returns what you expect. Below is the syntax and test:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION match_rows(arr1 ARRAY<FLOAT64>, arr2 ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
  RETURNS BOOL
  LANGUAGE js AS 
  """
  //array of common elements betweent the two arrays
  var common_el= [];
  for(i=0;i < arr1.length;i++){
    for(j=0; j< arr2.length;j++){
      if(arr1[i] = arr2[j]){
        //add to the common_el array when the element is present in both arrays
        common_el.push(arr1[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  //if the array of common elements has at least one element return true othersie false 
  if(common_el.length > 0){return true;}else{return false;}
""";

WITH input AS (
  SELECT STRUCT([5.0,6,7] as row, 'column2' as value) AS test
)
  SELECT
match_rows([4.0,4,6],[4.0,5,7]) as check_1,
match_rows(test.row, test.row) as check_2

  FROM input#, unnest(test) as test
```

And the output,

```
Row check_1 check_2
1   true    true
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION match_rows(arr1 ANY TYPE, arr2 ANY TYPE) AS (
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(arr1) el JOIN UNNEST(arr2) el USING(el)) > 0
);
SELECT match_rows([4,5,6], [5,6,7])
```